# Refactor multiple, similar requires (using Browserify)

Tags: node.js, browserify

I've got a very crude implementation working:

```
var screens = {
    a: require('./../react_components/screens/a.jsx'),
    b: require('./../react_components/screens/b.jsx'),
    c: require('./../react_components/screens/c.jsx'),
    d: require('./../react_components/screens/d.jsx'),
    e: require('./../react_components/screens/e.jsx')
};
```

Which works fine, however, I'd like to make it a little more scalable, so that when I change a filename, or add a new file to the `/screens` folder, I don't really have to keep updating this list of `require` statements.

I'm using Browserify, so I do have a build step I can hook into if need be (this will be ran in the browser)

Answer (score 0):

So for node/commonjs itself there are modules such as [requireindex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/requireindex) that will automate this kind of thing. However, the fact that these approaches determine the dependencies at runtime by looking at the filesystem defeats browserify's static analysis so I'm not aware of any of them that are browserify-compatible. Therefore, I'd suggest a code generation route where you use a module such as [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) to discover the files you want to export, but then write out a full `.js` file with the exports all statically coded, and point browserify at that file, which you can regenerate every time during your build step.

Comment: Thanks for this! Ended up finding this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bulkify and using `-t bulkify` to transform into the paths Browserify could understand...